# Sufficient condition on $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ to ensure the function $F:x \mapsto f(x^\top a)$ is geodesically convex on $n$-sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, spherical-coordinates, geodesic

Let $\mathbb S_{n-1}$ be the $(n-1)$-dimensional sphere in $\mathbb R^n$. Fix $a \in \mathbb R^n$ and  consider a function of the form $F(x) = f(x^\top a)$, for some one-dimensional function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

> **Question.** *What is a sufficient (and hopefully, necesssary) condition on $f$ for which
> $F$ is geodesically convex on $\mathbb S_{n-1}$ ?*

You may assume $f \in \mathcal C^2(\mathbb R)$.

**Definition.** Recall that if $\mathcal M$ is a manifold, then a function $G:\mathcal M \to \mathbb R$ is said to be geodescially convex iff $G\circ \gamma:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is convex for every geodesic curve $\gamma:[0,1] \to \mathcal M$. Geodesic strong-convexity, geodesic concavity, and geodesic strong-concavity are defined similarly.

### Examples of functions that I have in mind

- **Linear function.** $f(z) \equiv z$
- **Nonlinear functions.** $f(z) \equiv e^{z}$ or $f(z) \equiv \log(1 + e^{z})$.

Note that all of the above functions are convex in the usual sense in $\mathbb R^n$.

---

### Update: solution to case of linear function

Consider the case where $f(z) \equiv z$. One computes

- Euclidean gradient: $\nabla_{\mathbb R^n} F(x) = a$.
- Euclidean hessian: $\nabla_{\mathbb R^n}^2 F(x) = 0$.

Therefore, using standard formula, the riemannian hessian is
$$
\nabla_{\mathbb S_{n-1}}^2 f(x)[u] = P_{x}(\nabla_{\mathbb R^n}^2 f(x)[u]) - \mbox{trace}(x^\top \nabla_{\mathbb R^n}f(x))u = -F(x)u.
$$

Therefore if we define the spherical cap $H_a := \{x \in \mathbb S_{n-1} \mid x^Ta < 0\}$, then
$$
\nabla_{\mathbb S_{n-1}}^2 f(x)[u,u] = -F(x)\|u\|^2 = \begin{cases}\le 0,&\mbox{ if }x \in H_{a},\\\ge 0,&\mbox{ if }x \in H_{-a}\end{cases}
$$

and so $F$ is geodesically convex on $H_a$ and geodescially concave on $H_{-a}$.

Comment: Good question. Forgive my ignorance, is this notion of "geodesically convex" equivalent to the Hessian matrix being positive definite, in some appropriate sense?

Comment: That's definitely a valid question to ask. Yes,  indeed it's a theorem: *If $M$ is a an open geodesically convex subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $f$ is $\mathcal C^2$ on $M$, then $F$ is geodesically convex on $M$ iff $\nabla_M^2 f(x)$ is psd for every $x \in M$.* See Theorem 11.19 of http://sma.epfl.ch/~nboumal/book/IntroOptimManifolds_Boumal_2020.pdf

Comment: Thank you for recommending that book. It is a really interesting read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resulting function must be constant, since all geodesically convex functions on $S^n$ are constant.

for any function $f:S^1\to\mathbb{R}$, there is a corresponding periodic function $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. $f$ is geodesically convex iff $\tilde{f}$ is convex on any closed interval, which, by periodicity, is only the case if $\widetilde{f}$ is constant.

A geodesically convex function $f:S^n\to\mathbb{R}$ must be constant along all great circles by the previous argument, and thus $f$ must be constant on $S^n$, since any two points are joined by a great circle.

This result isn't specific to $S^n$: If I'm not mistaken, all geodeiscially convex functions are constant on any compact, connected Riemannian manifold without boundary.

Comment: Yes, indeed geo convexity of functions is usually motivated only on open subsets. My question as phrased doesn't quite make much sense. I really on interested in subsets of the sphere on which $F$ would be geo convex.

Comment: @dohmatob More specifically, it's common to restrict attention to geodesically convex domains, where convexity of functions behaves much the same as on convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Without this restriction, things are not so well behaved.